# C# limit options of enum in a derived class

Tags: c#, enums, derived-class

So I'm trying to limit the options ,of an enum I declared in the base class, I can select in the derived class.

```
namespace FLYNET.Personeel
{
    public enum Graad
    {
        Captain,
        SeniorFlightOfficer,
        SecondOfficer,
        JuniorFlightOfficer,
        Steward,
        Purser
    };

public abstract class VliegendPersoneelslid : Personeelslid
{
    public VliegendPersoneelslid()
    {
    }

    public override decimal BerekenTotaleKostprijsPerDag()
    {
        return BasisKostprijsPerDag;
    }

    public List<Certificaat> Certificaten { get; set; }
}
```

The above is the enum I'm trying to use from the base class Staff.
In the derived class Cabincrew I want to limit the options that can be selected in the constructor. If the wrong option is selected, it needs to throw a specified exception, so a bit like this :

```
namespace FLYNET.Personeel
{
    public class CockpitPersoneel : VliegendPersoneelslid
    {
        public int VliegUren { get; set; }

        public Graad Graad { get; set; }


            public CockpitPersoneel()
            {
                if (Grade = Graad.Steward || Grade = Graad.Purser)
                {
                    throw new Exception 
                }
            }

            public override decimal BerekenTotaleKostprijsPerDag()
            {
                decimal kostprijsPersoneel = 0m;
                decimal percentage;

                return kostprijsPersoneel;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm aware this is probably a beginners question (and it is :p) but please bear with me.

Comment: So, write the code like that and compile it. What happens? What is your question? Where does Grade come from in that constructor?

Comment: What do you mean by "selected in the constructor"? You're not accepting any parameters, which makes it very hard to check anything. (You'd also want to use `==` rather than `=`.) Your constructor also exists without being in a class, apparently. It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than pseudocode.

Comment: Also note that your enum isn't declared in the base class - it's a separate enum, which is almost certainly the right thing to do.

Comment: 1) you need to post the inheritance hirarchy for us to understand the relationship between the classes. I am talking about the code and declaration of the `Cabincrew` class. 2) `Grade` is the enum, if you want to check for it you need a variable of the type `Grade` then you can compare the value of this variable with certain enums values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using *extension methods* in order to hide options

```
public enum Grade {
   None, // <- zero option is often a good idea to include 
   Captain,
   SeniorFlightOfficer,
   SecondOfficer,
   JuniorFlightOfficer,
   Steward,
   Purser };

public static class GradeExtensions { 
  public static bool IsCabinCrue(this Grade grade) {
    return grade == Grade.Steward || grade == Grade.Purser;
  }

  public static bool IsCockpitPersonnel(this Grade grade) {
    return grade == Grade.Captain || 
           grade == Grade.SeniorFlightOfficer ||
           grade == Grade.SecondOfficer ||
           grade == Grade.JuniorFlightOfficer;
  } 
}
```

Then you can use extension methods as if their are methods of the enum when *validating* `Grade` values provided:

```
public class CabinCrue {
  ...
  public CabinCrue(Grade grade) {
    // Validation: Cabin Crue grade only
    // not Exception but ArgumentException: it's argument grade that's wrong
    if (!grade.IsCabinCrue()) 
      throw new ArgumentException("Cabin crue only", "grade");

    Grade = grade;

    ...
  } 

  public Grade Grade {
    get;
    private set;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This actually solved it for me and seemed like the easiest method to do it aswell, thanks Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in logic. You are trying to verify the `Grade` or `Graad` in the constructor. The property `Graad` cannot be set before the constructor call. Your validation will check the default value of the variable `Graad` (which in your case will be `Captain`).

You would need to pass the `Graad` into the constructor to be able to make that validation:

```
public CockpitPersoneel(Graad g)
{
    if (g = Graad.Steward || g = Graad.Purser)
    {
        throw new Exception("wrong choice");
    }
    else
    {
        this.Graad = g;
    }
}
```

What you also could do is to put the Validation logic directly into the full property and throw there the exception:

```
Graad _myGrade;

public Graad GradeOfPerson
{
    get { return _myGrade; }
    set
    {
        if (value = Graad.Steward || value = Graad.Purser)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not Allowed");

        }
        _myGrade = value; 
    }
}
```

this way you can leave your constructor blank:

```
public CockpitPersoneel()
{
}
```

Comment: So let me check if I understand this now : if I pass the (Graad g) into the constructor it enables me to verify if it is of a certain value of the enum and then throw an exception if it is. If it isn't then I just set the value to the parameter g I specified in the constructor?

Comment: @ArneVanstechelman yes that is correct. A better option is actually to really validate it in the setter of the property. Such setter are actually build for this validation stuff. But I also like the solution by Dmitry

Comment: "This will lead always to an NullReferenceException." In what way? What do you expect to be null?

Comment: @JonSkeet the variable of type `CockpitPersoneel`. The variable `Graad` has to be initialized before the constructor call for a plausible validation. I guess my wording is not very comprehensive. Any suggestion how to improve?=!

Comment: @MongZhu: I agree there's no plausible validation before it's set, but it's hard to see how you're expecting a `NullReferenceException` - I'd remove all statements about that.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, I changed it to point out that the default value of the `Graad` variable will be validated in the constructor.

Comment: Right - that's much more reasonable.